# Mod p reduction of geometrically irreducible polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

Let $f\in \mathbb Z[t,x]$ be a polynomial of positive degree that is irreducible over $\overline{\mathbb Q}[t,x]$. Is it true that for all but finitely many primes $p$ the reduced polynomial $f_p\in \mathbb F_p[t,x]$ is irreducible over $\overline{\mathbb F}_p[t,x]$? If yes, is there a way to determine all the finitely many primes for which this does not happen?

Comment: regarding first question: see EGA IV, partie troisieme, Prop. 9.7.8. If the generic fiber is irreducible, then there is an open neighbourhood over which fibers are geometrically irreducible. The complement of a non-empty open set in $\mathrm{Spec}\,\mathbb{Z}$ consists of finitely many points, I believe.

Comment: If it is irreducible over $\mathbb{C}$ then the Lefschetz principle applies (more precisely, you can use its proof)*, and so it is indeed true. However this proof does not give a way to determine the set of primes for which it doesn't happen

Comment: See: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/221921/geometrically-irreducible-variety/221926#221926

Comment: As for the bad primes, I think they are exactly the primes dividing the number $Res_x(Res_t(f,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}), Res_t(f,\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}))$.