# Is the reduction of an absolutely irreducible plane curve still irreducible except for the finite number of cases?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

Help me please.

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field (I am mainly interested in $k = \overline{\mathbb{Q}}, \overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$). Consider a plane curve $C \subset \mathbb{A}^2$ of degree $d$ over the rational function field $k(t)$. Suppose that $C$ is absolutely irreducible, i.e., irreducible over $\overline{k(t)}$.

Am I right that there is only the finite number $n$ of elements $t \in k$ such that the reduction of $C$ to $k$ is reducible ? Is there an upper bound for $n$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, $n$ is finite. No, there is no bound. If $a(t)$ is a polynomial with $n$ distinct roots, then $x^2+y^2=a(t)$ has degree $2$ and $n$ reducible fibers.

Comment: Is there an upper bound depending on degrees of the coefficients of $C$? In your example this is $n$.

Comment: The key fact you need is that being geometrically integral is a constructible property. This question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/221921/geometrically-irreducible-variety/221926#221926 is the analogous question over $\mathbb{Q}$ and the references given there also answer it in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an answer to the further question in the comments. The original question is answered in the comments (as was the further question while I was typing this :-)).

The vector of coefficients of a curve of degree $d$ gives a point in $\mathbb{P}^{N_d}, N_d = (d+1)(d+2)/2-1$. Multiplication of equations defines a map $\mathbb{P}^{N_r} \times \mathbb{P}^{N_{d-r}} \to \mathbb{P}^{N_d}$. The union of the images of these maps for $1 \le r \le d-1$ is a proper closed subset $X$ of $\mathbb{P}^{N_d}$ consisting of the reducible equations.

A curve over $k(t)$ can be viewed as a map $\mathbb{P}^{1} \to \mathbb{P}^{N_d}$ over $k$. If its image is contained in $X$ then the curve is not absolutely irreducible. Otherwise it only meets $X$ in a finite number $n$ of points and $n$ can be bounded as a constant depending on $d$ times the maximum of the degrees in $t$ of the coefficients of the curve.

Comment: Please clarify the last part: $n$ can be bounded as a constant depending on d times the maximum of the degrees in $t$ of the coefficients of the curve.

Comment: @DimaKoshelev It follows from Bezout's theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help !